# Using company iOS Developer for private iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I have an access to a comapny iOS Developer program and I was given an iPhone 4 for testing app. I wonder if it is possible to add//assign my private iPhone to the same account without letting admin know about that?

Comment: Not unless he pokes out his eyes. Whenever he would check on the account, he'll see another device added. Why are you sneaking, might I ask?

Comment: Haha, I'm not sneaking. I'm just curious because I would like to install iOS 7 on my phone during I have an access to this account :)

Comment: I hope I answered your Q. BTW, you better hope your admin doesn't have an account on this site, because he can see your face ;)

Comment: As I told this is not a big deal. This is my first face-off with developer program so I would like to know as much as possible about working with this!

Comment: Ask for permission, Pay the $99 or wait. Those are your options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.

If you add a device, whenever the Admin will check the account, he will probably notice another device has been added. I am not fully sure how it works with the company accounts, but I think the only difference will be that you Device ID would pop up under the "registered devices" section, not your name.

**BUT**

If you shouldn't do it, don't. If it doesn't matter if you do add your device, then just tell your Admin. But the company account can only provision to so many devices, so if those spots for devices are needed, then you could find yourself in a bit of trouble if you used one up for your personal iphone.

IMO, be a good boy. Do whats right (not saying your doing something wrong though).

Answer (score 1):

No, every single device registered will be listed under devices, in the developer center account, you can wait for iOS 7 it will be free to update, so be patient.

Comment: Okey, but it is not my problem if my phone will be listed under devices... I want to know if admin has to confirm my device or not? Because when I was 'registering' my company iPhone it worked out of the box - I only needed to login and mark it for development. Is there any option for admin to allow team account only to use one device?

Comment: There are 3 types of person in the team: Team agent, Team admin and Team member if you are a Team admin you can add the devices without confirmation, if you are a Team member when you try to add the device this request will be sent it to the Team agent and he need to approve this, here is the privileges table https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW1

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I wanted to see! Thank you very much!